# Embedding videos into the site from the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to development and looking for some help. I am creating a website in React, I have CRUD working on my site and I want to display youtube videos on the website. I have the titles and url's of said videos in the database using mongoDB and mLab. I do not see anywhere how to embed the videos besides just copying the share link from youtube. What I want to be able to do is input a video title and url (it adds the title and url into the database so my api works) and have that video display on my site. Is there anyway of doing so?

Comment: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ . stripslashes($row['videourl']) . '" title="title" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

This is what I am using right now and I get a video template for each video that I have in my database but there are playback errors. It doesn't display the video it just says "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback ID: 09ZLG_xWQDern_R4) 
Learn More"

Answer (score 0):

Using React I needed to capitalize the Iframe tag.

Comment: <IframeVideo url={video.video_url}/>